# TypeError: (data || []).forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, datatable, antd

I'm trying to render the data using ant design table but it doesn't work. I think it's because of the object key "children" in my response.

When I run my code I get the error:
**TypeError: (data || []).forEach is not a function**

I would also like to note that I have uploaded csv file data without "children" column and it works perfectly.

My response:

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { parse } from "papaparse";
import _ from "lodash";
import { Upload, message, Button, Table, Input } from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export default function Home() {

  const [columns, setColumn] = useState([]);
  const [baseData, setBaseData] = useState([]);
  const [filterTable, setFilterTable] = useState(null);

  const props = {
    name: "file",
    accept: ".txt, .csv",
    headers: {
      authorization: "authorization-text",
    },
    async onChange(info) {
      if (info.file.status !== "uploading") {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
      }
      if (info.file.status === "done") {
        const texts = await info.file.originFileObj.text();
        const results = parse(texts, {
          header: true
        });

        const col = _.keys(results.data[0]);

        const customCol = _.map(col, (value) => ({
          title: value,
          dataIndex: value,
          key: value.toLowerCase(),
        }));

        const data = results.data;
        
        console.log({ customCol });
        console.log({ data });

        setColumn(customCol);
        setBaseData(data);

        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
      } else if (info.file.status === "error") {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      }
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <Upload {...props}>
          <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
        </Upload>

        <Table pagination={false} columns={columns} dataSource={filterTable == null ? baseData : filterTable} />
        
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the table props:

```js
export interface TableProps < RecordType > extends Omit < RcTableProps < RecordType > , 'transformColumns' | 'internalHooks' | 'internalRefs' | 'data' | 'columns' | 'scroll' | 'emptyText' > {
  dropdownPrefixCls ? : string;
  dataSource ? : RcTableProps < RecordType > ['data'];
  columns ? : ColumnsType < RecordType > ;
  pagination ? : false | TablePaginationConfig;
  loading ? : boolean | SpinProps;
  size ? : SizeType;
  bordered ? : boolean;
  locale ? : TableLocale;
  onChange ? : (pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record < string, (Key | boolean)[] | null > , sorter: SorterResult < RecordType > | SorterResult < RecordType > [], extra: TableCurrentDataSource < RecordType > ) => void;
  rowSelection ? : TableRowSelection < RecordType > ;
  getPopupContainer ? : GetPopupContainer;
  scroll ? : RcTableProps < RecordType > ['scroll'] & {
    scrollToFirstRowOnChange ? : boolean;
  };
  sortDirections ? : SortOrder[];
  showSorterTooltip ? : boolean;
}

export interface TableProps < RecordType = unknown > extends LegacyExpandableProps < RecordType > {
  prefixCls ? : string;
  className ? : string;
  style ? : React.CSSProperties;
  children ? : React.ReactNode;
  data ? : RecordType[];
  columns ? : ColumnsType < RecordType > ;
  rowKey ? : string | GetRowKey < RecordType > ;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `(data || []).forEach` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you've shared, so we can't help you undestand why `data` doesn't have `forEach`. At a guess, it's an object that isn't an array.

Comment: I checked on my Table props `dataSource` from AntDesign and there are `data` and `children` props inside the node modules files. I've updated my post so you can understand more @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Please add which line the error is coming or create a gist or codepen for the issue

Comment: Please add which line the error is coming or create a gist or codepen for the issue

Comment: Please add which line the error is coming or create a gist or codepen for the issue

Answer (score 2):

Ant design uses the **children** property in your data to display a **tree structure** in your table, and it accepts an array not a string, thus the error. You can tell the Table component to use a different name for this feature by using the **childrenColumnName** prop, like this :

```
<Table childrenColumnName="antdChildren" />
```

Read more about the table tree data structure [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-tree-data)